# C execl execute PHP script dont show result in STDOUT

Tags: php, c

I'm having trouble with a daemon done in C , which reads the stdout php content and saves the contents to a file. The problem happens only for a PHP script file, while another does not.
If I invoke the script manually, you write the contents on stdout normally.

After giving fork , I am running the following code snippet:

```
void startScriptCollector(char *php , char *collectorName , char *collectorRaw , char *collectorLog){
    char str_script[80];
    char str_raw[80];
    char str_log[80];
    int result = 0;
    int fd_output , fd_error; //File Descriptor

    setreuid(geteuid(), geteuid());

    //stat_rtrim(collectorLog);
    //removeChar(collectorLog,'\n');
    if(collectorLog != NULL) trim(collectorLog);

    tmLogPrintf(Log, TMLOG_LEVEL_ERROR , "On startScriptCollector collectorName : %s , collectorRaw : %s , collectorLog : %s...\n",
            collectorName, collectorRaw , collectorLog);
            //exit(-1);

    sprintf(str_script  , "%s/%s" , SLAVIEW_CUSTOM_SCRIPTS , collectorName);
    sprintf(str_raw     , "%s/%s" , SLAVIEW_CUSTOM_TMPCOL   , collectorRaw);
    sprintf(str_log     , "%s/%s" , VARDIR                  , collectorLog);

    fd_output = open(str_raw, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY , 0777);
    fd_error  = open(str_log, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY , 0777);

    if(fd_output < 0){
            tmLogPrintf(Log, TMLOG_LEVEL_ERROR , "Script %s not could save data in %s...\n",
            collectorName , str_raw);
            exit(-1);
    }

    if(fd_error < 0){
            tmLogPrintf(Log, TMLOG_LEVEL_ERROR , "Script %s not could save error log ...\n",
            collectorName);
            //exit(-1);
    }

    dup2(fd_output , 1); //write on data  file
    dup2(fd_error  , 2); //write on error file

    result = execl(PHPEXEC , "php" , str_script  , NULL);


    if(result == -1){
            tmLogPrintf(Log, TMLOG_LEVEL_ERROR , "Error, on execute script  %s ...", collectorName);
            exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason you're giving error . It was the relative path to the PHP libs . Or I could change the path programmatically through the c or through PHP and everything would be fixed! Then a friend who works with me add fullpath tested on PHP and the script ran normally.